# Content change on front page

Tags: seo, url, blog, content, publishing

I am building a blog type website with articles. In one category, new articles will be posted every 2-3 days. I need the last article from that category to be (totally) displayed on the front page with sharing options comments.

Once a new article is posted, the old one gets a specific URL and is put in his category.

I was wondering the impact it has on SEO to change that article periodically on the front page. As shares made on the featured article will share my home page, will the old articles still benefit from their rank once the URL has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question/doubt is just a matter of remembering the right position for each thing. The post is a unit of content and the home page is a "bucket" that gets filled with content units.

The content of the post itself will be, most probably, on a database or file, which means that is not coded on to the home page itself, so the post should have it's own URL to access directly.

Then, since you want to show it's content on the home page, you only have to print the content of the most recent post there, but you should link the title, or some other part of the home page to the URL of the post itself. That means, that even when the home page will change content, the post itself won't and so, the site will keep the relative ranking it has. It will go up or down acording to all the aspects related to success or failure.

Consider that all the blogs have changes on the home page, that is part of the "freshness" of the site and yours won't be different in that aspect.

All the interaction related to each post will still be on that page/post, sharing on social media, comments, etc.